# Second consecutive swipe action not opens the swipe action in swift

Tags: swift

[MGSwipeTable](https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell) is used in our project to handle swipe action in table view. The problem is when I swipe action one row and its actions are shown. then I swipe action another row, the previous swipe action is closed but this row is not opened. So we need to swipe action again.

```
func swipeTableCellWillBeginSwiping(_ cell: MGSwipeTableCell) {
    DLog("Starts Swiping")
}

func swipeTableCellWillEndSwiping(_ cell: MGSwipeTableCell) {
    DLog("End Swiping")
}
```

Suppose that this is my list:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

I swipe action on "line 1". the "delete action" is shown
I don't tap anywhere and I just swipe action on "line 3"
This makes "line 1" to be in normal mode("delete" action is not shown)
But it does't open the "line 3" swipe action.
To do so, I need to swipe action on "line 3" again

Comment: That is a restraint by iOS. You can probably write a `hacky` workaround. But since iOS users are already expecting the intended functionality, I would highly recommend against modifying it as it results in a bad UX.

Comment: @Malik Thanks. you'r right. But in some apps (I think Mail app) it is not like this